# Evaluating integrals of exponents using Cauchy's Integral theorem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate using Cauchy's integral theorem: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ {e^{e^{\sin x}}}\ dx $$

I was asked this question in college and don't know where to start. There was a similar question but it wasn't asked properly and doesn't have any answers.

Comment: so cachy's integration formula states: $$f(a)\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$ and work based the principle of singularities I believe

Comment: I was told the integral could be solved using Cauchy's theorm, but I don't see how one would even start.

Comment: I think that you would normally find the positions of any asymptotic points then integrate for a new function $$\frac{g(z)}{z-z_1}$$ where $g(z)$ is our new function and $z_1$ is a singularity, but finding such points for this function is also difficult

Comment: Hint:

From Cauchy's theorem, choosing $\gamma: e^{i\theta},\, \theta\in[0,2\pi]$, and the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$, 

\begin{align}
2\pi f(0)&=\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{iz}\,dz \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} f\left(e^{i\theta}\right)\,d\theta \qquad \text{as }dz/iz=d\theta
\end{align}

Comment: @Zachary - except that is the Integral formula again, not the Integral *Theorem*, which states that $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$ when $f$ is analytic in a simply-connected domain containing $\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is closed.